# htaccess: domain hosted on subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a website hosted under www.mydomain.com/myniceweb, and I bought the domain www.myniceweb.com

It works fine, but I don't want the visitors to be able to see the subfolder (www.mydomain.com/myniceweb), and I don't want google to think there are 2 different websites with the same content...

I tried modifying the .htaccess file with no results:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?myniceweb.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myniceweb/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myniceweb/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?myniceweb.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ myniceweb/index.php [L]
```

I want to "redirect" the users that access www.mydomain.com/myniceweb to www.myniceweb.com How can I do this?

I would be grateful for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I finally did it and I want to share it with you guys...it may help someone with the same issue:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/farmaciagimeno.com(.*)$ http://www.farmaciagimeno.com$1
```

writing this into your .htaccess (the one located in the /myniceweb folder, not the root folder), any request to yourdomain.com/myniceweb is going to be redirected to www.myniceweb.com

Comment: I happened to have the same problem as you (a single hosting containing two different websites; one in the root folder the other in a subfolder) and after uploading the new .HTACCESS file nothing happened. Isn't this instantaneous? Any hint of why is not working in my case?

Answer (score 1):

> I have a website hosted under www.mydomain.com/myniceweb, and I bought the domain www.myniceweb.com
>
> It works fine, but I don't want the visitors to be able to see the subfolder (www.mydomain.com/myniceweb)

I don´t understand your Question.
You have a DOMAIN **www.myniceweb.com** and the content of your website
is located under the root folder **/myniceweb** Right??

Why see your visitors the Link **www.mydomain.com/myniceweb**??

If you don´t want Google Robots etc. on your subfolder,
change your robots.txt to something like that:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /myniceweb
```

You can make a 301 Redirect like this in your htaccess.:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.myniceweb.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you are using PHP as Script Language you can put this code in the top of your header:

```
<?php 
$file=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 
if(substr(dirname($file),1)=="myniceweb") {
Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
Header( "Location: http://www.myniceweb.com" ); 
} 
?>
```

It checks if your Document Folder == myniceweb, then you will be redirected to **www.myniceweb.com** else make nothing

Comment: exactly; the content of www.myniceweb.com is located under www.mydomain.com/myniceweb

Thanks for the suggestion about Google robots, but I am also interested in "redirecting" the users that access www.mydomain.com/myniceweb to www.myniceweb.com

How can I do this?

Comment: thank you again but now when i go to www.mydomain.com/myniceweb it redirects me to www.mydomain.com. I want to be redirected to www.myniceweb.com !

Comment: Oh sorry: simple change the Link in your htaccess to : www.myniceweb.com/ I have edited it in the post above.

Comment: Now I am getting a redirect loop when I access www.myniceweb.com :S