# htaccess domain redirect to newdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have the domain www.oldsite.com and i set a redirect to forward to www.newsite.com/new

but when i google search old site all of its sub links go to www.newsite.com/new/sublink

How do i edit the htaccess file so that the sub links never pass though

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.com*$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\/new" [R=301,L]
```

In short all links involved in oldsite.com should redirect to newsite.com/new

I read the below but it didnt seem to help to much.
[htaccess: domain hosted on subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781800/htaccess-domain-hosted-on-subdirectory)

Comment: You don't need the `"` quotes or ``\`` backslashes in the oldsite/newsite bits...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below `.htaccess` should be place on the root folder of the old domain only:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newsite.com/new [R=301,L]
```

It will redirect anything from the old domain to the new one, for example:

```
http://oldsite.com/someurl
```

Will go to:

```
http://www.newsite.com/new
```

No URLs from the old site will be passed down to the new site, they will all be sent to `/new`.

**NOTE:** *make sure you do not have any additional `.htaccess` files in other folders of the old domain as those will set null the previous rules.*

---

If you want to send only the main domain to the new one without any URLs within:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.newsite.com/new [R=301,L]
```

---

A different way would be to handle all the URLs on the new site, which would be like the below `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newsite.com/new%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

It will redirect anything from the old domain to the new one, for example:

```
http://oldsite.com/someurl
```

Will go to:

```
http://www.newsite.com/new/someurl
```

If you do not wish the new to show up simple remove `/new` from the rule above.

Comment: Perfect, Nailed It, Thanks

Comment: Very nice and detailed answer.